# Cannot import model from App1.models while App.2 is importing App1's models

Tags: django

Obviously it's a circular import, however I need to know how to break it and still keep my functionality.

My app `Profile` has a model called `Notification`, this `Notification` model has a `ForeignKey` related to my `Track` model which is in my other app `Submission`. `Submission` also has a model called `Comment` and this has a save method which is supposed to also create a `Notification`.

Inside Profile.models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Submission.storage import OverwriteStorage
from Submission.models import Track
from django.core.cache import cache 
from project import settings
from datetime import datetime   

Profile.models.py:
    ...

class Notification(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='reciever')
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sender')
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, related_name='track')
    content_type = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Notification, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # Call the "real" save() method
        UserProfile.objects.filter(id=self.user.userprofile.id).update(unread_notifications=True)
```

This imports "Track" as you can see, now inside Submission.models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from Submission.storage import OverwriteStorage
from Profile.models import Notification

class Track(models.Model):

    ...

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=False)
    track = models.ForeignKey(Track, unique=False, related_name = 'comments')
    content = models.TextField(max_length=450)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=True)
    edited = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    replies = models.ManyToManyField('Comment', blank=True)
    score = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        notification = Notification(user=self.track.user, sender=self.user, track=self.track, content_type='comment', content=self.content)
```

So here you can see I am creating a notification when a comment is created. However I cannot do this because I have to import Notification from Profile which already is importing Track from Submission. I can create the notification in my views, but I feel like that's not the django way.

Comment: You haven't explained why you need to import Track into Notification.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Whoops, sorry. The notification needs a Track to be associated with. So the user can click the notification in the UI and it will take them to the track that was commented on. Edit: I've added the missing code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to import Track into Notification. Django allows you to refer to models in a ForeignKey definition as as a string, in the format "appname.ModelName". So:

```
track = models.ForeignKey("Submission.Track")
```

Note your related name makes no sense here; they are for the name of the reverse relationship from (eg) Track back to Notification, which is a collection, so it makes no sense to call that "Track". Remove that, so that Django uses the default `notification_set`.

Also note you don't really need to import Notification into Submission, either; your notification could be created using those same reverse relationships, without referencing the model directly at all:

```
notification = self.track.notification_set.create(user=self.track.user, sender=self.user, content_type='comment', content=self.content)
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver, I did not know I could use a string in a FK. Thank you!